# Specifying the correct response type in swagger

Tags: scala, swagger, swagger-ui

I have the following case class in play framework model which is wrongly displayed in swagger-UI as an array.

```
case class ComponentAvg(@ApiModelProperty (value="..",
  example="2.722", dataType="String")  
                        value: String)
```

I wonder how I can fix that such the the response type will be of type ComponentAvg.

This is how the response appears in swagger-UI example:
[
  {
    "value": "2.722"
  }
]

Answer (score 0):

If you add @ApiResponses then it may fix the issue.
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/annotations-1.5.x#apiresponses-apiresponse